# How to remove a stuck (maybe melted) connector from the blower motor resistor

Tags: electrical, wiring, stuck-bolt, caravan, connector

I have a 2003 Dodge Caravan in which the blower motor just blew out due to melted wiring at the connection of the blower motor cable and the blower motor resistor (picture attached).

[image: melted]

I've gotten replacement parts for the blower motor and resistor but I'm trying to unplug the connector on the left (blue wires which lead to somewhere else in the vehicle) from the resistor. It was very tight going in and now I can't get it out. I'm concerned (but not convinced) that the plastic may have melted fusing the connector to the resistor. I've tried pulling and prying it out but it won't budge. I've cut away much of the plastic from the resistor to expose the connector further but still it won't move.

[image: cut]

Does anyone have advice on how to get this out? I'd really prefer not to cut the cables and buy a new connector for $30+.

Thanks!

Comment: blew out due to melted wiring, or melted wiring due to it blowing out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The connector will need to be replaced. It looks to be fused together. The metal connector terminals were the cause of the original problem. The usual problem is that the connector makes poor contact due to loose fit in the female terminals this causes resistance and therefore heating of the connectors.

Comment: This is correct.  The connector can and should be replaced.  Once the contacts corrode and melt the plastic nearby, even if you can separate the connector from the resistor, you'll simply move the overheating contact problem to the new resistor and it'll happen again.

Comment: Okay, so just to confirm, even though the green wire connector on the right is the one that looks to be the source of the problem, if I keep the blue wire connector on the left, it will still cause issues in the future?

Comment: If a connector is misshapen enough that it will not come out with normal force then it is too damaged to be reused. I would be concerned that the connector pins will not line up correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Dont you have to remove the connector with the green/black wire also? In your photo it looks like the connectors are melted together. You can get a knife and try to seperate them first.

The blue wires goes to your blower speed setting switch on dash. The green/black wire goes to the blower.

Even if you remove the connector. The old connector may not fit to new resistor if it is deformed. So a new resistor/connector is probably required. I have seen many times the places which sell used resistors in good condition with connectors attached (wires cut but you can reconnect to your wires).

If not, you may get away with cutting the wire and using cheap female flat connectors (if you can find right size). They are cheap. I doubt that you can find a replacement connector part without the wiring loom.

Even perhaps solder the wires directly to the old resistor, you already seem to have cut the plastic around so you would have plenty of working room there.